# MVC DropDownListFor Issue w/ key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Just need another set of eyes. Error is:

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'BrandId' is of type 'System.Int32'
but must be of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.
```

HTML

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BrandId, Model.BrandForDropDown, "- Brand -")
```

Controller

```
model.BrandForDropDown = Repository.GetBrandsForDropDown();
```

---

```
    public SelectList GetBrandsForDropDown()
    {
        if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
        {
            return new SelectList((from store in DataContext.Stores
                             join userstore in DataContext.UserStores on store.StoreId equals userstore.StoreId
                             join brand in DataContext.Brands on store.BrandID equals brand.BrandID
                             where userstore.UserId == userId
                             select new SelectListItem
                             {
                                 Value = brand.BrandID.ToString(),
                                 Text = brand.BrandName
                             }).OrderBy(x => x.Text));
        }

        return new SelectList(new List<Brand>());
    }
```

Model

```
public int BrandId { get; set; }
public SelectList BrandForDropDown { get; set; }
..others omitted
```

I've also tried `List<SelectListItem>` as well in the model and view, etc, same error

Comment: Is that error after post back where you're returning the same view?

Comment: @Izzy no this is initial view load

Comment: The same error message can also occure if your `SelectList` has no data

Comment: @Izzy you were right on the empty btw.....

Comment: Glad I could help! it can be a very misleading error at times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has one problem. You need to specify the dataValueField and dataTextField when you created the selectlist. So either you have to do that in the server method or in when you use it in the view.

This is how you do that in your method

```
select new SelectListItem
                      {
                        Value = brand.BrandID.ToString(),
                        Text = brand.BrandName
                      }).OrderBy(x => x.Text),"Value","Text");
```

Another option is to simply change the property type to `List<SelectListItem>` and update your method to return that type.

```
public int BrandId { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> BrandForDropDown { get; set; }
```

Make sure you return the same type when your if condition fails

```
public List<SelectListItem>GetBrandsForDropDown()
{
  if(Membership.GetUser() != null)
  {
    // your existing code
                 select new SelectListItem
                 {
                       Value = brand.BrandID.ToString(),
                       Text = brand.BrandName
                 }).OrderBy(x => x.Text));
  } 
  return new List<SelectListItem();
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Please follow my trick .

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.BrandForDropDown = Repository.GetBrandsForDropDown();
```

**HTML**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BrandId, ViewBag.BrandForDropDown as   
List<SelectListItem>, "- Brand -")
```

Thanks .